# Number line to number sentence

Tags: arithmetic

i have to solve a question.Question statement is :
What number sentence does this number line not illustrate?
[image]

options are

a. $-4-(-3)+5=4$

b. $4+(-5)-3=-4$

c. $-4+3-(-5)=4$

d. $4-3-5=-4$

e. All of the above work

I searched some youtube tutorial related to number line but unable to solve it .Please provide reference link related to this question.

Comment: Please check if those number sentences are true, to start with!

Comment: a), b) and c). d) is not true

Comment: apology for typo now i corrected it.

Comment: $d$ is not described by the picture.  Indeed, it's fine to say that $4-3$ is described, which takes us from $4$ to $2$.  After that though, you are either subtracting an additional $2$ or adding $-2$.  You are not subtracting $5$.  Thus $4-3-2-3=-4$ is described, but not $d$.